# How to sum with joined tables with Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have 2 related entities - Category and Expense. Expense has a date - when the expense was made.

A Category entity has a one-to-many relationship with multiple Expense entities which themselves have a name(product) and a price property.

I want to calculate the sum of all expense->price properties for a single category for the current month. (I have working findExpensesForMonthAndCategory method)

Can you help me please?

**Category**

```
class Category
{
    protected $name;
    protected $expenses;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->expenses = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

**Expense**

```
class Expense
{
    protected $category;
    protected $product;
    protected $price;
    protected $date;
}
```

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30398/discussion-between-nifr-and-faery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are actually 2 ways of solving this.

**Solution 1**

Add a getExpenseSum() Method to your Category entity...

```
class Category 
{

// ...

    public function getExpenseSum() 
    {    
        $sum = 0;
        foreach ($this->expenses as $expense) {
            $sum += $expense->getPrice();
        }

        return $sum;
     }
```

Now you can output the sum in twig this way:

```
     {{ category.expenseSum }}
```

**Solution 2**

create a method in your repository.

```
// src/Vendor/YourBundle/Entity/ExpenseRepository 

public function getSumByCategory($category)
{
    $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->sum('e.price')
        ->where('e.category = :category')
        ->setParameter('category', $category)
        ->getQuery();

    return $q->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Isn't there any way to automatically let Doctrine do that query on the entity? Doctrine knows about the relationship and the datatype - so it would be great to do this with some kind of annotation on a new property.